# Использование Кэша

Tags: java, кэширование

Есть класс Cache, который выполняет роль примитивного кэша. Как сделать, чтобы пользователь класса не знал, что там есть кэш (т.е. сделать невидимым извне)?

```
public class Cache extends LinkedHashMap<String, HashMap<Character, Integer>> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final int MAX_ENTRIES = 50;

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest) {
        return size() > MAX_ENTRIES;
    }
}
```

Приложение считывает с консоли слова или выражения и считает количество уникальных символов, если в кэше есть такая строка, то берет из кэша иначе считает и ложит в кэш.

Код где используется кэш

```
public class UniqueCharsCounter {
private static final int ONE_CHAR = 1;
private static HashMap<String, HashMap<Character, Integer>> cache = new Cache();

public String count(String text) {
    checkPreconditions(text);
    HashMap<Character, Integer> characters;
    if (cache.containsKey(text)) {
        characters = cache.get(text);
    } else {
        characters = countUniqueChars(text);
        cache.put(text, characters);
    }        
    return buildCharactersConclusionColumn(characters);
}
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что именно вы имели ввиду, но подозреваю, что вас интересует прозрачное применение сквозной логики. Если да, то AOP - то, что вам нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно можно сделать и на AOP как вам посоветовали в комментариях, но на мой взгляд это сильно громоздко. Тут подойдет что-то типо паттерна Декоратор. Хотя все равно будет видно, что вы используете кэш, при создании класса, но как бы и вслучае с AOP это тоже видно, просто намного менее явно ) В общем выбирать вам, вот пример декоратора:

```
public interface UniqueCharsCounter {
    public int count(String text);
}

public class UniqueCharsCounterImpl {
    public int count(String text) {
        checkPreconditions(text);
        return countUniqueChars(text);
    }
}

public class UniqueCharsCounterCache {
    private UniqueCharsCounter decorated;

    public UniqueCharsCounterCache(UniqueCharsCounter toDecorate) {
        this.decorated = toDecorate;
    }
    public int count(String text) {
        if (cache.containsKey(text)) {
            characters = cache.get(text);
        } else {
            characters = decorated.count(text);
            cache.put(text, characters);
        }        
        return characters;
    }
}
```

Заодно получается и разделение логики подсчета, логики кэширования и логики формирования вывода (ваш `buildCharactersConclusionColumn(characters);`) Single Responsibility, красота )

**UPD**
Я на самом деле не знаю, нужно ли вам выносить в отдельный класс `buildCharactersConclusionColumn(characters);`. Если он формирует одинаковые результаты для одинаковых параметров (то есть функция чистая, без побочных эффектов) то его вполне можно тоже закэшировать. Тогда метод `count` будет такж евозвращать String. Если же побочные эффеты есть (например вы включаете текущее время), тогда нужно разделять. Я предположил, что второй вариант - именно ваш, потому что вы не кешируете коде результат работы `buildCharactersConclusionColumn`.